# Dealing with a commonly abused tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

The situation is this:

[radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) should be

> Radio is the transmission of signals through free space by electromagnetic radiation of a frequency significantly below that of visible light, or a device for doing the same. Radios are typically used for communication including voice, video and data. This includes Wi-fi, Bluetooth, Mobile phones, GPS, Radar, some remote control devices and near field communication devices (NFC) such as contactless smartcards.

But it should not be used for the radio button GUI element (there's the [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button) tag for that).

However, [searching for `[radio] is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[radio]+is%3Aquestion) yields **~1,300** results at the moment, and when you just [try to remove all results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=[radio]%20is%3aquestion%20-[html]%20-[jquery]%20-[javascript]%20-[angularjs]%20-[php]%20-[css]%20-[swift]%20-[button]%20-[forms]) that include tags that make it *very* probable OP should have used [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button) instead, you just get around **420** results, still including plenty [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button) candidates.

So, we have a tag that is probably 80%-90% of the time abused; yet, looking at the "correctly" tagged question it **is** a useful tag.

What does one do in such a situation? I don't feel like [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request)ing this, because there's too many "good" questions tagged [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio). Is there a way to batch-retag, e.g. only all questions with tags [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio)[html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html)?

---

**Clarification**: I'm well aware that maybe using something clearer like  [radio-transmission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-transmission) in the future would be a *good idea*™, but it won't "rescue" the "correctly" tagged [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) questions, nor would it avoid ambiguity in the future – people that should use [radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-button) will continue to use [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) (it's curious that people interested in basic UI elements are bad at using the Stack Exchange UI :D ).

I especially doubt doing something along modifying the [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) excerpt to start with *"DON'T USE THIS TAG FOR RADIO BUTTONS"* would help -- people who use [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) wrongly probably simply did not read the tag description at all.

---

I asked for tag renaming [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308320/rename-tagradio-to-tagradio-transmission-manually-retag-most-tagradio) and for community support in manual retagging, too.

Comment: "Abuse" is a big word, it is just clumsy tag entry by the questioner.  They use [radio][button] instead of typing the dash.  And don't notice that it rearranges to [button][radio] after posting :)  It is merely a decent contextual tag, about every language runtime and operating system has them so its selective power is zilch.  [Button] is already enough to summon somebody that knows UI in the primary tag.  Just fix it whenever you run into it.

Comment: @HansPassant: They don't use [tag:radio] [tag:button], they just [tag:radio] in 90% of cases (use my excluding search, and remove the [tag:button] element from the list of excludes). In fact, there's but about 300 questions  [tag:radio] [tag:button]!

Comment: Yes, but if you synonym [tag:radio] to [tag:radio-transmission] then retag every question that isn't about [tag:radio-transmission], then you end up with two unambiguous tags and [tag:radio] never to be used again. That is basically what the answer below says.

Comment: @TinyGiant: good point! I didn't consider inventing a new tag to synonym it to [tag:radio] so far; however, I personally can't check / retag 1300 questions, so adding a tag synonym *now* would just extend the problem to the new tag, right?

Comment: If there are truly 1300 questions in that tag that refer to radio-buttons instead of radio-transmissions, then yes it is a daunting (but not impossible) task. But the first step IMO would still be to create the synonym in order to stop new posts from adding that tag. Moderators can synonym tags relatively easy. Then a retag effort can be made, you can enlist the help of other users to do this. Often [asking in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) can help.

Comment: Hm, I just tried that, it says I need 5 rep on the tag -- of course, I first retag before I answer, and of course, I added the [tag:software-defined-radio] tag to disambiguate those questions about SDR (which is a special area of radio technology), so I don't have 5 rep, @TinyGiant :(.

Comment: To propose a synonym request using the mechanism yes, but if you make a post on meta about it (or adapt this one) then a moderator can do it. Of course, before a moderator will do that it needs to show a considerable amount of support from the community.

Comment: The tag excerpt for [tag:radio] is a big part of the problem, and needs to be cleaned up. It is a technical definition of "radio", but contains no usage guidance. A good excerpt would be short, and quickly describe what sort of question the tag _should_ be used on.

Comment: Not trying to go supernegative on SE here, but It is a rather telling statement about the SE UI that _even the UI people_ are bad at using the SE UI.

Comment: @Aaron Not really. There are lots of novices designing UIs out there. I think I was about 12 when I started tinkering with them.

Comment: @Mogsdad Yet, the fact that it describes what radio is should probably be a pretty big clue that questions tagged with that should actually be about radio. Of course, this is assuming that people actually read the tag wiki, which seems rather unlikely in most of these cases.

Comment: @reirab Right - even a good tag wiki excerpt won't get read by all users. But the current [tag:radio] tag fails pretty much every measure of [what a tag wiki excerpt should contain](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts).

Comment: You're right about the futility--people label [tag:javascript] as [tag:java] routinely.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ideally people would read the tag excerpt and realize the correct usage, but since that is not happening, then best option is to try to eliminate the confusion.

So people type in [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) and since they think it *could be* the right tag, they select it, so you need to provide more information in the tag itself to discourage misused.  **Renaming** [radio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio) to [radio-frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-frequency) would likely accomplish your goal.  Renaming is a moderator only function, but would eliminate all of the potential issues and future ambiguity except the existing questions.

As a side note, in my experience, the term "radio" generally refers to the physical transmitter/receiver hardware and not the electromagnetic waves used to carry the signal, so the terminology in the tag name is probably more accurate as well.

---

To address your other question, there is no bulk update utility available to users or moderators.  The retagging will have to be manually (devs obviously have access to the database, so it theoretically could be done, but isn't normally done and this doesn't seen to be the type of issue that would justify this step).

Comment: Well, I do agree. But: adding a new tag [tag:radio-frequency] now won't help the 420 good [tag:radio] questions, nor will it avoid ambiguity of using [tag:radio] in the futute; so I don't think your answer actually *solves* the issue of the *existence* of the [tag:radio] tag.

Comment: @MarcusMüller He does address it, the retagging has to be done manually. Basically everything currently tagged with radio will have to be changed to radio-button, radio-transmission or have the tag removed altogether.  Usually this occurs after someone post an answer specifically stating this and it garners enough votes to show that the community agrees.  At that point various people usually start to help to do the retagging.  Once the retag is done, the tag will disappear.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I never said "add a new tag".  I said rename "radio" (that is a moderator only function).  That solves every problem except the existing questions, which need to get done manually.

Comment: Opened tag rename request: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308320/rename-tagradio-to-tagradio-transmission-manually-retag-most-tagradio

Comment: I just wanted to explain that I didn't favor [tag:radio-transmission] over [tag:radio-frequency] for anything but the fact that [tag:radio-transmission] describes what the [tag:radio] tag's description currently does. I do agree that [tag:radio-frequency] is a broadly used term, but it only describes a single  specific detail of radio technology.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think [tag:radio-transmission] is much superior to [tag:radio-frequency]. For programming, the frequency itself is probably not a topic that needs its own tag; it would best be considered one aspect of making the transmission.

Comment: IMHO "radio" is the topic. "radio-waves" are the propogated electromagnetic signal. "radio-frequency" is the frequency band

Comment: I agree that radio-transmission is much better than radio-frequency (which describes a band of the e-m spectrum, not the concept of communicating, scanning, etc. with signals in that band,) but I also completely agree with Bohemian that just 'radio' is really the correct name for this topic.