# Should [presto] be renamed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

According to tag descriptions of [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto) and [prestodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestodb), most (if not all) questions tagged 'presto' are about "Presto - the database" and not about "Presto - the deployment tool".

It seems people do not read tag descriptions too carefully when tagging their questions.
Assuming people in general won't change their habits in near future, what can be done about this situation?

(I edited tags of a few most recent questions under 'presto', rerouting them to 'prestodb', so ~recent month of questions is "fixed".)

Comment: "It seems people do not read tag descriptions too carefully", people read them at all?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Most of the time I read unless I am using it very frequency.

Comment: @IamtheMostStupidPerson I think you are the exception... well, technically an exception.

Comment: "Should we chango [presto]?"

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308285/65458 suggests that the cure would be to rename the [presto] tag, but it takes an moderator to do that. Is there a process for this?

Comment: Or, maybe, [presto] tag should be redefined to mean "Presto - the database"?

Comment: "Is it tabien [presto] to fix this tag?"... I hope nobody who actually speaks good spanish reads that

Comment: Suggestion for once the tag renaming is complete: "hey [presto]"

Comment: "Presto" is (was) also the name of the JS engine used in the old Opera browser, there seem to be [3 questions about it tagged \[presto\]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[presto]+opera)

Comment: Any thoughts? Quite a few people spend their time looking at this  -- i appreciate that! -- however, it would be good to actually make the change and, forgive me my ignorance, I don't know what is the next step.