# Merge [prestodb], [prestosql] and [presto] in a single tag: [presto]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Here are currently three tags, and they all basically mean "Presto, the SQL query engine".

Context, i.e. how we arrive at the current situation:

1. There was tag [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto) which meant something completely unrelated (a deployment tool)
2. A [prestodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestodb) tag was created for "Presto, the SQL query engine"
3. Some people would use [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto) tag (without reading it description) to tag Presto questions.

   - Virtually all [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto) questions were about "Presto, the SQL engine", not about the deployment tool
   - I asked for the cleanup of the tags ([Should [presto] be renamed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365395/should-presto-be-renamed))
   - Eventually [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto) tag was redefined to mean "Presto, the SQL query engine" and was made a synonym of the [prestodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestodb) tag
4. Presto Foundation was founded (https://prweb.com/releases/prweb16070792.htm). In the Presto community, "prestodb" now means "Facebook's Presto", so [prestodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestodb) tag on Stack Overflow no longer has a suitable, neutral name.
5. A [prestosql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestosql) tag was created ([presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto) could not be used, as it's a synonym and I cannot make it not a synonym).

Today we have three tags: [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto), [prestodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestodb), [prestosql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestosql). We need just one. Please merge the tags into a single [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto) tag.

Comment: If we merge all to the presto tag, then wouldn't there again be ambiguity between the deployment tool and the SQL engine? Can you come up with a different tag name?

Comment: @BhargavRao there are no questions about the deployment tool in last few years.

Comment: Still, it is always preferred to have a clear tag name. It is fine if the tag name is a bit long, but being clear is what we need.

Comment: I don't think there is any confusion.  I can't even google for that dead project anymore.

Comment: I had to go to the second page of Google to find it. https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=presto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a few small button clicks and presto! the merge is done.

I merged the tags together and now there's just one tag [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto). The [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto) -> [prestodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prestodb) was added a synonym by 5 users, and therefore it was not merged in the first place. Some of the questions in the tag were not related to presto DB. For example, questions about Opera's older versions (Presto), which had to be tagged [opera-presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opera-presto) instead. Thanks to them being synonyms and not merged tags, the search wasn't making it easy to find out the wrongly tagged posts, therefore I merged all the tags and retagged the ones that were about Opera Presto retroactively.

There also seems to be [3 questions about the deployment tool](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpresto%5D%5Bdeployment%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0), which we need to create a new tag for. I *still* think that we need to have a more descriptive tag name for [presto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/presto), to prevent it from being misused, but given that the other usages are rare, it probably can be retagged to the correct tag.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure getting rid of `[prestodb]` and `[prestosql]` altogether is going to work... it seems `prestodb` and `prestosql` are now distinct projects, having split around January of this year & with stated intention for the projects to diverge. That means eventually some posts tagged under `presto` will only be relevant to one of the forks... https://github.com/prestodb/presto https://github.com/prestosql/presto https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/380

Comment: `[prestodb]` was already a synonym of `[presto]`, albeit in the reverse direction, @Michael. There were 7 questions in `[prestosql]`, out of which 5 already had the `[presto]` tag.  Anyway, you do have some arguments agents having a single tag for all, can you post an answer detailing all these? I can recreate these tags, if needed.

Comment: @MichaelChirico yes, the projects will diverge. Same applies to AWS Athena which (as of now) is branched off from Presto 0.172 release. Yet, most "how do I query?" questions of Athena users apply to any Presto version. For Athena-specific queries, we use `amazon-athena` tag. Over the time, we may need to introduce some new tags to distinguish between projects. Having a clean state today will allow that.

Comment: @PiotrFindeisen yes, agree it probably makes sense to merge now for the clean slate as you said. What I had in mind is something like Python has where many questions apply to 2.7.x or 3.x equally & the standard appears to be to use `[python]` and `[python-2.7]` (etc) to tag Qs which could be version-specific...